# File last changed time earlier than it was last opened

Tags: linux, command-line, nfs

Why is the file last changed time dated **earlier** than time shown by the previous `date` command?

```
$ date
Fri May 17 13:41:11 MDT 2013
$ touch other.rst 
$ ll other.rst 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ondrej cnls 59261 May 17 13:39 other.rst
```

This disrupts my `make` cycle, as my latest changes are not picked up sometimes...

Here is some info about my computer:

```
$ uname -a
Linux kittiwake 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The filesystem is NFS-mounted. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by our admin --- the date on the NFS server was two minutes behind my own computer time. Syncing the time on the NFS server fixed the issue:

```
$ date
Fri May 17 13:54:32 MDT 2013
$ touch other.rst 
$ ll other.rst 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ondrej cnls 59261 May 17 13:54 other.rst
```

Now things work.

Interesting, I didn't know there could be such an issue.

Comment: Such issues were common in the previous century.  Tell your admins to get their acts together and run [`ntpd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) on the servers (and on all your workstations and pcs).